# python execute formatted string, SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, syntax-error

The thing sounded to be pretty simple
I've string, written into file, it's the formatted string as a string 
I mean, file looks like this:

```
f\"Welcome {member.name}\\nNice to see you\"
```

So the code sees it like this:

```
'f"Welcome {member.name}\\nNice to see you"'
```

Then I've just placed it into exec() branch, so it's like this:

```
with open('welcome.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

for member in members:
    temp = exec(data)
    print(temp)
```

Though the only thing I get back is this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\grzes\PycharmProjects\Mash_The_CharacterCreator\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/grzes/PycharmProjects/Mash_The_CharacterCreator/bot.py", line 335, in on_member_join
    temp = exec(serverConfig[str(member.guild.id)]['Welcome_Msg'])
  File "<string>", line 1
    f\"Welcome {member.name}\\nNice to see you\"
                                               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Does anyone knows why does this happen, and how to solve this?

Comment: Can't end an f-string or even a raw string with a backslash `\ `

Answer (score 0):

i,ve got it like:

```
print(f"Welcome {member.name} \nNice to see you")

with open('welcome.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

for member in members:
    exec(data)
```

- print(temp) will give you a None, so i deleted it,
- used print on the formatting line instead

Answer (score 0):

It should be
`print(f'Welcome {member.name}\nNice to see you')`

You shouldn't need all of those backslashes, just the one for a newline